# <button> image vs text alignment

Tags: html, css

[image]

as you can see in the image, when I use an image with just regular text the buttons are not aligned, if I use all text or all image it aligns perfectly as seen below. i'm assuming this is a css problem?

```
<div style="text-align:center; border:1px solid; border-radius:5px; width:500px; margin: 10px auto 0px auto;">
    <button type="button" onClick="parent.location='cal<?php echo $pyear;?>.php'" style="height:50px; width:50px;">
         <?php echo $pyear;?>
    </button>
    <button type="button" onClick="parent.location='../index.php'" style="height:50px; width:50px">
         <img src="../css/images/home_25.png" />
    </button>
    <button type="button" onClick="parent.location='cal<?php echo $nyear;?>.php'" style="height:50px; width:50px;">
         <?php echo $nyear;?>
    </button>
</div>
```

working example with all images as buttons.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `image` is aligned to the baseline of the text.  Simply use `vertical-align: top` on all 3 buttons.

```
<div style="text-align:center; border:1px solid; border-radius:5px; width:500px; margin: 10px auto 0px auto;">
    <button type="button" onClick="parent.location='cal<?php echo $pyear;?>.php'" style="vertical-align: top;height:50px; width:50px;">
         22222
    </button>
    <button type="button" onClick="parent.location='../index.php'" style="vertical-align: top;height:50px; width:50px">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/30/30" />
    </button>
    <button type="button" onClick="parent.location='cal<?php echo $nyear;?>.php'" style="vertical-align: top;height:50px; width:50px;">
         11111
    </button>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2LNQn/

Comment: worked perfectly, I have a side question, does it matter if I enter the last ; for example: style="height:50px; width:50px"> or does it need to be style="height:50px; width:50px;"> would using the first method cause any problems?

Comment: The last one is optional, whether or not you "should" is debatable.

Comment: @AlbertD : you myt wanna accept the answer fella if that helped!! :)